# Python twitter API can't find my handle

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to get my followers list on Twitter using the Twitter API.  I use the following code:

```
import twitter

CONSUMER_KEY = '...'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '...'
OAUTH_TOKEN = '...'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = '...'

auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)
print twitter_api.VerifyCredentials

twitter_api.GetFollowers(user_name='cjisalock')
```

The OAuth is working, but I get the following error:

```
TwitterHTTPError: Twitter sent status 404 for URL: 1.1/GetFollowers.json using parameters: (oauth_consumer_key=...)
details: {u'errors': [{u'message': u'Sorry, that page does not exist', u'code': 34}]}
```

Obviously this user exists (since it is me!), but I do not see what I am doing wrong.  I have also tried to replace user_name with user and screen_name but get the same error.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

---

UPDATE:

Here are things that have NOT worked...

```
twitter_api.GetFollowers(user_name='cjisalock')
twitter_api.GetFollowers(screen_name='cjisalock')
twitter_api.GetFollowers()
twitter_api.GetFollowers(user='cjisalock')
```

I also tried resetting my OAuth tokens to no avail and upgrading my twitter module to the latest.

However, I HAVE been able to make it work (within the rate limiting, that is) with tweepy:

```
auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

if(api.verify_credentials):
    print 'We sucessfully logged in'

list= open('FollowersList.txt','w')

user = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="cjisalock").items()

while True:
    try:
        u = next(user)
        print(u.screen_name)
        list.write(u.screen_name +' \n')

    except:
        print 'We got a timeout ... Sleeping for 15 minutes'
        time.sleep(15*60)
        u = next(user)
        print(u.screen_name)
        list.write(u.screen_name +' \n')

list.close()
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: According to this page: https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/examples/view_friends.py you should just do `twitter_api.GetFriends()`

Comment: Is there then a method to get the friends of a different twitter user?  (As in, I would like to create a social graph for a few layers.)

Comment: According to https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/twitter/api.py#L1416 you'd do `twitter_api.GetFriends(screen_name='some_user')`

Comment: So I did just that: users = twitter_api.GetFriends(screen_name='cjisalock')
print [u.name for u in users] and got the same error.